# Spark Include tag with variable in href

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine, castle-monorail

I want to include a spark view in another spark view.
I've tried to use the [include tag](http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/organizingcontent#Includingfiles).

But it doesn't seem to support variables as part of the href attribute.
Eg.

```
<include href="_group_${groupData.Type}.spark" />
```

Does anyone know of any workaround to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `<include>` tag is part of the Spark language that gets parsed on the first pass and cannot include variables of its own because the view class file has not yet been generated for the variables to be evaluated. Using `<include>` is a means of including a static resource of some kind.

I think the thing you may be looking for is the `<use import="myFile.spark"/>` tag for including other Spark files, or you could just use Spark `Partials` built in. The problem however is that you're trying to have the included spark files dynamically determined at runtime which I don't think will be possible.

Is there any way you can pre-generate the views for each `groupData.Type` value using the pre-compilation ability in Spark?

The other option potentially (if you really do need these dynamic at runtime) is to create and maintain an `InMemoryViewFolder` instance and you can add "virtual" files to it as you pull them out of the database but you still won't get away with using variables inside any Spark language elements because variables "don't exist" at that point in the parsing/rendering pipeline.

Hope that helps,
Rob

Comment: Hi Rob,
Thanks for the explanation, I've come up with a workaround for it:

<use if="groupData.Type == 'AP'" file="_group_ap.spark" /> ...